# ATI radeon hd 5450 Graphics Card Issues

Tags: windows-7, boot, graphics-card, amd-radeon, dell-optiplex

I have an Old Dell Optiplex 755 SFF with an Intel Core 2 Processor (windows 7). Now This can hold a PCI-E x16 port. Now I got an ATI Radeon HD 5450 low profile. I plugged and played and it fits without a hitch, the software installed too! , now for the graphics well... It doesn't really work at all as it seems to freeze at the moment that it loads on the windows logo. It loads into safe mode so I'm not really sure what the problem is. Any ideas, I read the dell forums and they should be somewhat compatible... with the specs so I'm at a loss here. and I am a novice here. Ideas?

Edit I have tried to reset the cmos,no luck there. I have tried to move the ram as well. nothing big happened.

Comment: I am guessing you installed the software before the card?  Your problem is a driver problem.  Your attempted solutions don't make a great deal of sense, your BIOS settings, wouldn't have anything to do with Windows crashing because of a driver.

Comment: Yea, I did install the drivers after and still no luck.

Comment: I did remove the software completely and I tried to install the device in safe mode, no luck since I get an error that won't let me start the installation

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that installing software before installing the hardware was probably a bad idea. I removed any trace of it via drive sweeper

http://downloads.guru3d.com/Guru3D---Driver-Sweeper-%28Setup%29_d1655.html

I then did a standard clean install, worked without a hitch!

Comment: Drive Sweeper may work fine, but just an FYI... AMD has an official driver remover intended to remove all traces of AMD Graphics drivers called AMD Clean Uninstall Utility that can be downloaded here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Clean-Uninstall-Utility.aspx